# My bouncing moving ball is not rotating. HTML CSS animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make this ball bounce, move and rotate using keyframe animations. I have made the ball move and bounce so far, but when i try to make it rotate the ball just goes random. Can someone help me fix it?

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bouncing Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style17.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="ball" src="pelota.png">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.ball{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    animation:mover 3s linear infinite alternate, 
              bounce 1s ease-out infinite,
              rotar 1.5s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes mover {
    from {
        left: 0;
    }
    to {
        left: calc(100% - 200px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,100% {
      transform: translateY(653px);
      height: 30px ;
      width: 55px;
    }
    40%,90%{
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateY(500px);
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
  }

  .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    animation: mover 3s linear infinite alternate, disminuir 1s ease-out infinite;
    bottom: 5px;
  }

  @keyframes disminuir{
    50%{
      height: 5px;
      transform: scaleX(0.5);
    }
  }

  @keyframes rotar{
    100%{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

First post btw. I want the ball to rotate propertly.

Comment: You can't put two separate `transform` on one div. All transforms have to be on one line, else they will overwrite each other. A solution could be to make an extra child div that rotates.

Comment: Hello, I dont understand. The animations in .ball work as intended if they are like this.  The thing that makes the ball behave extrange without rotating is the animation rotar(¿?) or the keyframe rotar. Sorry for bad english and thank you.

Comment: can you try this demo? https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/medL4rtf/
and please let me know if you want to see any more changes.